# Final specifier for virtual methods and vtable lookup

Tags: c++, c++11

I have observed that when a method of certain class is marked as `final` in C++11, there is no lookup in the vtable to call that method, even from pointers, at least with the assembly produced by GCC. Let this code serve as example:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() : retval(0) {}
    virtual ~Base(){}
    virtual int method() {
        return retval;
    }
protected:
    uint32_t retval;
};

class DerivedFinal : public Base {
public:
    int method() final {
        return retval + 2;
    }
};

int main() {
    Base *bptr = new Base();
    DerivedFinal *df = static_cast<DerivedFinal *>(bptr);
    return df->method();
}
```

Please note that the code uses return value like this to make the assembly code easily readable.

The assembly of main looks like this:

```
<+0>:     push   %rbp
<+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
<+4>:     push   %rbx
<+5>:     sub    $0x18,%rsp
<+9>:     mov    $0x10,%edi
<+14>:    callq  0x400750 <_Znwm@plt>
<+19>:    mov    %rax,%rbx
<+22>:    mov    %rbx,%rdi
<+25>:    callq  0x400900 <_ZN4BaseC2Ev>
<+30>:    mov    %rbx,-0x18(%rbp)
<+34>:    mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
<+38>:    mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
<+42>:    mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
<+46>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
<+49>:    callq  0x400986 <_ZN12DerivedFinal6methodEv> // This is the method call
<+54>:    add    $0x18,%rsp
<+58>:    pop    %rbx
<+59>:    pop    %rbp
<+60>:    retq
```

As it can be seen, the method is called without any vtable lookup (this does not happen if the method is not marked final). The code behaves the same way even if there are classes that inherit from `DerivedFinal` My question here is... is this standard behavior?

---

**EDIT**: Let's rewrite the code in such way that is not undefined behavior, to explicitly show how the vtable is skipped when the method is final, and it is looked up when it is not:

```
class Base {
public:
    Base() : retval(0) {}
    virtual ~Base(){}
    virtual int method() {
        return retval;
    }
protected:
    uint32_t retval;
};

class DerivedFinal : public Base {
public:
    int method() final {
        return retval + 2;
    }
};

class DerivedNotFinal : public Base {
public:
    int method() {
        return retval + 3;
    }
};

int main() {
    DerivedFinal *df = new DerivedFinal();
    DerivedNotFinal *dnf = new DerivedNotFinal();
    int res_final = df->method();
    int res_not_final = dnf->method();
    return 0;
}
```

And the assembly dump:

```
<+0>:     push   %rbp
<+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
<+4>:     push   %rbx
<+5>:     sub    $0x28,%rsp
<+9>:     mov    $0x10,%edi
<+14>:    callq  0x4007b0 <_Znwm@plt>
<+19>:    mov    %rax,%rbx
<+22>:    movq   $0x0,(%rbx)
<+29>:    movl   $0x0,0x8(%rbx)
<+36>:    mov    %rbx,%rdi
<+39>:    callq  0x400a5c <_ZN12DerivedFinalC2Ev> // First ctor...
<+44>:    mov    %rbx,-0x18(%rbp)
<+48>:    mov    $0x10,%edi
<+53>:    callq  0x4007b0 <_Znwm@plt>
<+58>:    mov    %rax,%rbx
<+61>:    movq   $0x0,(%rbx)
<+68>:    movl   $0x0,0x8(%rbx)
<+75>:    mov    %rbx,%rdi
<+78>:    callq  0x400a82 <_ZN15DerivedNotFinalC2Ev> // Second ctor...
<+83>:    mov    %rbx,-0x20(%rbp)
<+87>:    mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
<+91>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
<+94>:    callq  0x400a34 <_ZN12DerivedFinal6methodEv> // Call to DerivedFinal::method directly
<+99>:    mov    %eax,-0x24(%rbp) // Save result in stack
<+102>:   mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
<+106>:   mov    (%rax),%rax
<+109>:   add    $0x10,%rax
<+113>:   mov    (%rax),%rax
<+116>:   mov    -0x20(%rbp),%rdx
<+120>:   mov    %rdx,%rdi
<+123>:   callq  *%rax // Call to DerivedNotFinal::method via vtable (indirect call)
<+125>:   mov    %eax,-0x28(%rbp) // Save result in stack
<+128>:   mov    $0x0,%eax
<+133>:   add    $0x28,%rsp
<+137>:   pop    %rbx
<+138>:   pop    %rbp
<+139>:   retq
```

With this example the behavior is also clear. The call to DerivedFinal::method does not require any vtable lookup, while the call to DerivedNotFinal::method requires an indirection. In my opinion, this behavior (with the final keyword) is desired in certain performance-critical applications, which is why I ask if the behavior is standard.

Comment: Well, start with the fact that your code invokes undefined behavior...

Comment: @T.C. Yes sir, this `DerivedFinal *df = static_cast<DerivedFinal *>(bptr);` here lands OP into UB land (:

Comment: I know the exaple is a little nasty, I designed it so on purpose, to illustrate that even though the vtable is pointing to `Base::method`, the actual call is `DerivedFinal::method` because the vtable is completely skipped (because the compiler thinks `df` is pointing to a `DerivedFinal` object)

Comment: That is actually proper behavior on the compiler's part.  There is no point looking up in the vftable if the method is final.  Note that a pointer of type T* can only point to an object of type T or types G where T is an ancestor of G.  For this reason, there is no other implementation of that method.

Comment: Could you please turn your example into something without UB? This would greatly improve the questions. Maybe also add an example without `final` to have a comparison? Then rephrase this as: "Does `final` allow more compiler optimizations?"

Comment: A little nasty?  "I wrote some code that executes undefined behavior.  The behavior resulting isn't what I expected!  What happened?"

Comment: It's maybe worth mentioning that the code was compiled **with no optimizations** (-O0) explicitly, so the aforementioned behavior is the code that the compiler issues normally.

Answer (score 5):

Your code invokes undefined behavior, by `static_cast`ing a pointer to something that isn't a `DerivedFinal` into a `DerivedFinal *`.

The compiler is entitled to do anything, including making your cat pregnant or conjuring nasal demons.

In a saner example, a method marked `final` cannot be overridden in a further derived class, so the compiler may - and a good optimizing compiler should - devirtualize the call.

Answer (score 1):

The standard just specifies behaviour. In the absence of undefined behaviour, the program must behave *as if* the virtual function were looked up based on the object's dynamic type; but nothing in the standard specifies that it must actually do a run-time lookup, if the compiler can determine the correct override.

Since you have a pointer to `DerivedFinal`, and the override for that class is `final`, the compiler knows which override must be chosen, so can generate a non-virtual call to that. It doesn't have to account for the possibility that you might use `static_cast` to lie about the type; that causes undefined behaviour, so it's allowed to do anything in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The standard permits any machine code that reproduces the required effect of the source code.

<del>If this machine code does that, i.e. if it calls `Base::method`, then it's OK.</del>

<del>And otherwise, not.</del>

---

Please do note that this code has formally Undefined Behavior, by treating a `Base` object as an object of class `DerivedFinal`.

As such it could really do anything whatsoever and still be conforming.

But I'm guessing that well-behaved code that exhibits the same phenomenon, with that particular compiler and options, can be created. Also, such a cast was used by Microsoft for their ATL library, in order to magically make some member functions inaccessible (prevent inadvertent use of them). So it's apparently well-defined with the Visual C++ compiler, and most likely also with g++ – but then we're into very compiler-specific territory.

---

In case you're wondering *why* the compiler can omit a lookup here, since the member function is `final` in the statically known type, it can't be overriden by some derived class. And so the member function implementation in the statically known type can be called directly. Hence I suspect that the machine code above calls `DerivedFinal::method`, as it's allowed to due to the formal UB, and as is indicated in the disassembly.

Comment: That code was meant to be used as example. For instance, if the method is not marked `final`, then the assembly **looks up in the vtable** and as a result, `Base::method()` is called (because the pointer is actually pointing to a Base object, due to the static_cast).

Comment: *such a cast was used by Microsoft for their ATL library, in order to magically make some member functions inaccessible (prevent inadvertent use of them)*.  Can you elaborate on this?  Do you know specifically where in ATL does this happen?  Code like that is wrong, and I would be surprised if Microsoft explicitly uses this intentionally.  There is the IUknown vs INondelegatingUnknown, but these are explicitly defined as interfaces, which are MS compiler specific constructs.

Comment: Also note that IUnknown and INondelegatingUnknown are not ATL constructs.

Comment: @ethang: That took some research to dig up again. But e.g.  `CComPtrBase::operator ->` is declared as `_NoAddRefReleaseOnCComPtr< T > * operator ->( ) const throw( );`. The internal mechanism here is a downcast to a class derived from `T` where `AddRef` and `Release` are non-`public`. This prevents inadvertent client code calls to `AddRef` or `Release` , because all such calls should be managed by the smart pointer.

Comment: @ethang: re "Code like that is wrong, and I would be surprised if Microsoft explicitly uses this intentionally." he he :)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf as it happens, so long as you control the compiler and choose to define what happens when particular kinds of undefined behavior happen, you can use that in C++ code.  In this case, it seems like using a nuclear bomb to solve a roach problem.

Comment: That is pretty hokey!  I guess they do control the tools, and they also don't want people to take the source (which is given out with the tools) and move to a different platform.  In fact, this is not as bad a sin as you think.  The class T needs to be inherited from IUnknown, which is an interface (keywords interface and __interface), which is a Microsoft specific extension.  It may very well be within the rules they defined.  interface allows for many features that facilitate dynamic typing which are not supported by c++.